# How in JS write a better function which has many IF conditions based on a value and need to return based on it

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find out a better solution to write a function that accesses a JSON OBJ.

The OBJ contains countries and nested data as examples:

```
{
  "us": {
    "accessCode": "accesscode.wav",
    "noAccessCode": "noAccessCode.wav",
    "redirecting": "redirecting.wav",
    "thanksForCalling": "thanksForCalling.wav",
    "notRegisteredPhone": "notRegisteredPhone.wav",
    "noSitePhoneAssigned": "noSitePhoneAssigned.wav",
    "noCandidatePhoneNum": "noCandidatePhoneNum.wav",
    "noCandidate": "noCandidate.wav",
    "errorOccurred": "errorOccurred.wav"
  },
  "it": {
    "accessCode": "accesscode.wav",
    "noAccessCode": "noAccessCode.wav",
    "redirecting": "redirecting.wav",
    "thanksForCalling": "thanksForCalling.wav",
    "notRegisteredPhone": "notRegisteredPhone.wav",
    "noSitePhoneAssigned": "noSitePhoneAssigned.wav",
    "noCandidatePhoneNum": "noCandidatePhoneNum.wav",
    "noCandidate": "noCandidate.wav",
    "errorOccurred": "errorOccurred.wav"
  }
}
```

The function I built so far needs to return the data of the JSON based on a country passed.

The example is below but with many ifs will become ugly probably and I would like to find a different way of doing it. Just imagine if we would have 100 countries.

```js
const obj = {
  "us": {
    "accessCode": "accesscode.wav",
    "noAccessCode": "noAccessCode.wav",
    "redirecting": "redirecting.wav",
    "thanksForCalling": "thanksForCalling.wav",
    "notRegisteredPhone": "notRegisteredPhone.wav",
    "noSitePhoneAssigned": "noSitePhoneAssigned.wav",
    "noCandidatePhoneNum": "noCandidatePhoneNum.wav",
    "noCandidate": "noCandidate.wav",
    "errorOccurred": "errorOccurred.wav"
  },
  "it": {
    "accessCode": "accesscode-it.wav",
    "noAccessCode": "noAccessCode-it.wav",
    "redirecting": "redirecting-it.wav",
    "thanksForCalling": "thanksForCalling-it.wav",
    "notRegisteredPhone": "notRegisteredPhone-it.wav",
    "noSitePhoneAssigned": "noSitePhoneAssigned-it.wav",
    "noCandidatePhoneNum": "noCandidatePhoneNum-it.wav",
    "noCandidate": "noCandidate-it.wav",
    "errorOccurred": "errorOccurred-it.wav"
  }
}

const getAudioByCountry = (country) => {
  // Simplified but will have more countries
  if (country === 'IT') return obj[country.toLowerCase()];
  if (country === 'FR') return obj[country.toLowerCase()];
  if (country === 'DK') return obj[country.toLowerCase()];
  if (country === 'SV') return obj[country.toLowerCase()];
  if (country === 'ES') return obj[country.toLowerCase()];
  // Default to english
  return obj.us;
};

console.log('With country :::: ', getAudioByCountry('IT'));
console.log('With no country :::: ', getAudioByCountry());
```

Comment: why not just return `obj[country.toLowerCase()];` - all your ifs seem to just do that?

Comment: Do note that the code you execute for all conditions is the same: `return obj[country.toLowerCase()]`. So there's **no point** having those different conditions at all…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While `.includes` would help:

```
if (['IT', 'FR', 'DK', ...].includes(country)) {
  return obj[country.toLowerCase()];
}
```

Capitalizing the country and checking whether it exists on the object would be even better.

```js
const obj={us:{accessCode:"accesscode.wav",noAccessCode:"noAccessCode.wav",redirecting:"redirecting.wav",thanksForCalling:"thanksForCalling.wav",notRegisteredPhone:"notRegisteredPhone.wav",noSitePhoneAssigned:"noSitePhoneAssigned.wav",noCandidatePhoneNum:"noCandidatePhoneNum.wav",noCandidate:"noCandidate.wav",errorOccurred:"errorOccurred.wav"},it:{accessCode:"accesscode-it.wav",noAccessCode:"noAccessCode-it.wav",redirecting:"redirecting-it.wav",thanksForCalling:"thanksForCalling-it.wav",notRegisteredPhone:"notRegisteredPhone-it.wav",noSitePhoneAssigned:"noSitePhoneAssigned-it.wav",noCandidatePhoneNum:"noCandidatePhoneNum-it.wav",noCandidate:"noCandidate-it.wav",errorOccurred:"errorOccurred-it.wav"}};

const getAudioByCountry = (country = '') => obj.hasOwnProperty(country.toLowerCase())
  ? obj[country.toLowerCase()]
  : obj.us;

console.log('With country :::: ', getAudioByCountry('IT'));
console.log('With no country :::: ', getAudioByCountry());
```

Answer (score 2):

You could return either the wanted language or the default language

```
const
    getAudioByCountry = country => obj[country.toLowerCase()] || obj.us;
```